# How to find the maximum on 3 or more arrays at each index

Tags: python, numpy

So I am basically trying to get the maximum (minimum, or any similar opration for that matter) on 3 parallel numpy arrays for an image processing application.

The thing is, for given arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 34, 5]
b = [3, 5, 6, 1]
c = [4, 62, 12, 6]
```

I want to obtain a similar array like:

```
maxArray = [4, 62, 34, 6]
```

in which each element is the maximum for the common index in the arrays.

There is an obvious approach with classic and naïve programming techniques but I am interesed in a vectorized way, since I just can't wrap my head around it.

Am I maybe thinking of this the wrong way? You tell me. Thanks before hand!

Comment: Use `np.max`, `np.max([a,b,c], axis=0)`

Comment: Join them into one array (`np.array` or `np.stack`) and take the `max` on the new dimension.  The function form, `np.max` does that for you.  But if you are going to apply several operations to the same list, make the new array first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the number and size of the arrays, but typically using `functools.reduce` together with `np.maximum` will be one of your best options, because it avoids array stacking which is comparatively expensive since it involves a full copy of all sub-arrays, but does use vectorized functions on the arrays we are given:

```
from functools import reduce                                 
import numpy as np

# make example
N = 1000,
a,b,c,d,e = (np.random.random(N) for _ in "abcde")

# my proposal
def f_pp():
    return reduce(np.maximum,(a,b,c,d,e))                            

# @yatu's
def f_yatu():                     
    return np.max((a,b,c,d,e),0)

# @rusu_ro1 1st
def f_rr_1():
    return [max(x) for x in zip(a, b, c, d, e)]

# 2nd
def f_rr_2():
    return list(map(max, zip(a, b, c, d, e)))

# rusu_ro1 modified by pp 1st
def f_rr_pp_1():
    return [*map(max,a,b,c,d,e)]

# 2nd
def f_rr_pp_2():
    return np.fromiter(map(max,a,b,c,d,e),float,1000)

# timings and check
all_funcs = {k:v for (k,v) in globals().items() if k.startswith('f_')}
for k,v in all_funcs.items():
print(k,timeit(v,number=1000),'correct',np.all(f_pp()==v()))
```

Sample run:

```
# f_pp 0.012913539074361324 correct True
# f_yatu 0.025256304070353508 correct True
# f_rr_1 0.8206795542500913 correct True
# f_rr_2 0.7683364972472191 correct True
# f_rr_pp_1 0.7669085101224482 correct True
# f_rr_pp_2 0.7993066972121596 correct True
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers! Each and everyone is useful and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

1) applying max buil-in function over elements with common index in the arrays using zip inside a list comprehension:

```
[max(e) for e in zip(a, b, c)]
```

2) similar with :

```
list(map(max, zip(a, b, c)))
```

output:

```
[4, 62, 34, 6]
```

3) or @yatu suggestion:

```
np.max([a,b,c], axis=0)
```

output:

```
array([ 4, 62, 34,  6])
```